# Перезагрузка Apache с помощью PHP

Tags: apache, php

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста нужно перезагружать Apache с помощью php скрипта!

Comment: есть функция наз exec! но не могу найти файл apache перезагрузки

Answer (score 1):

Апач для вашего php-скрипта будет родительским процессом, поэтому грохать его, хоть и можно, но не нужно.

Лучше создайте из php какой-нибудь файлик, который послужит флагом: нужно перегрузить апач. Отдельный скрипт будет регулярно запускаться, например, при помощи `crond` или `at`, и смотреть наличие такого файлика: если есть, то будет перегружать сервер.

Сделайте для этого отдельный суидный скрипт, в котором пропишите (один из вариантов, зависит от версии апача, операционки и т.п.):

```
apachectl -k restart
service apache restart
service apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
/etc/rc.d/init.d/httpd restart
```

Или, еще лучше, сделайте беспарольный ключ и запускайте через ssh:

```
ssh -i key-file user@localhost service apache2 restart
```

Вообще-то, можно запускать апач и не от рута, но тогда вы не сможете набиндить его на порт 80; что, в свою очередь, можно побороть редиректом в `iptables`.

Comment: я понял! можно бы ещё например sheduled но просто я не знаю файл в Apache перезагрузки! у меня Apache 2.2